# Building static-library Graphviz for iPhoneOS. What script?

Tags: ios, graphviz

I'm desperate: (I've tried all kinds of scripts and none works.
My system is xCode4.3.2 on Lion (10.7.4) with iOS-SDK v5.1

With the script:

```
#!/bin/sh
# For iPhoneOS, see http://clang.llvm.org/ for options
export DEV_iOS=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer
# was /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer
export SDK_iOS=${DEV_iOS}/SDKs/iPhoneOS5.1.sdk
export COMPILER_iOS=${DEV_iOS}/usr/bin
export CC=${COMPILER_iOS}/clang
export CXX=${COMPILER_iOS}/clang++
export LDFLAGS="-arch armv7 -pipe -Os -gdwarf-2 -mthumb -isysroot ${SDK_iOS}"
export CFLAGS="${LDFLAGS}"
export OBJCFLAGS="${LDFLAGS}"
export CXXFLAGS="${LDFLAGS} -fvisibility-inlines-hidden"
export LD=${COMPILER_iOS}/ld
export CPP=${COMPILER_iOS}/clang
export AR=${COMPILER_iOS}/ar
export AS=${COMPILER_iOS}/as
export NM=${COMPILER_iOS}/nm
export CXXCPP="${COMPILER_iOS}/clang++"
export OBJC=${COMPILER_iOS}/clang
export RANLIB=${COMPILER_iOS}/ranlib

./configure \
    --build=arm-apple-darwin11 \
    --host=arm-apple-darwin11 \
    --disable-dependency-tracking \
    --enable-shared=no \
    --enable-static=yes \
    --enable-ltdl=no \
    --enable-swig=no \
    --enable-tcl=no \
    --srcdir=${GVROOT} \
    --with-codegens=no \
    --with-cgraph=no \
    --with-graph=yes \
    --with-expat=no \
    --with-fontconfig=no \
    --with-freetype2=no \
    --with-ipsepcola=yes \
    --with-libgd=no \
    --with-quartz=yes \
    --with-visio=yes \
    --with-x=no
```

I get the error:

```
checking build system type... arm-apple-darwin11
checking host system type... arm-apple-darwin11
checking for a BSD-compatible install... /usr/bin/install -c
checking whether build environment is sane... yes
checking for a thread-safe mkdir -p... config/install-sh -c -d
checking for gawk... no
checking for mawk... no
checking for nawk... no
checking for awk... awk
checking whether make sets $(MAKE)... yes
checking for style of include used by make... GNU
checking for arm-apple-darwin11-gcc... /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin/clang
checking whether the C compiler works... no
configure: error: in `/Users/xaviersantamaribech/Developer/graphviz-2.28.0':
configure: error: C compiler cannot create executables
See `config.log' for more details.
```

Can anyone tell me what script I can use in my system (XCode4.3.2 - iPhoneSDK5.1 - Lion 10.7.4) to get the static library Graphviz for IOS.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

there is no support yet for running Graphviz in iOS

Comment: Thank you. But I see that there are people in the forum who managed to compile the library for iPhone and asked for the script to my software combination.